# Lambda as a function parameter -> accept methods only from particular class

Tags: kotlin, lambda, parameter-passing

I wish to find solution to force `emit(S.() -> S)` function to accept as parameters, only methods from generic `S` class. Current solution accepts all lambda methods which returns S.
S is a generic class which has methods to reduce/modify own parameters. I want only those methods to be called in `emit`. It guarantees that every method passed to emit is "pure function" (all methods in S are pure)

```
val _uiState = MutableLiveData<S>() 
var state: S
fun emit(reduction: S.() -> S) {
        state = reduction.invoke(state)
        if (_uiState.value != state) {
            _uiState.postValue(state)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need this?

Comment: Do you mean that only appropriate object type that is allowed to call `emit` is `S`?

Comment: do you really need to reset the `state` here? wouldn't it also work to just use a consumer instead? e.g.: `fun emit(reduction: S.() -> Unit) { reduction(state) }`? ... you can't really prohibit the usage of other functions... or to say it the other way around: you do not need to use the given lambda parameter... you can also completely ignore it...

Comment: I edited question to give a little bit more context (it was not obvious what I try to do)

Comment: It would not be possible without some sort of sandboxing, which incurs too much overhead, unless your lamda may come from untrusted source though. The general consensus on restricting what client code can do is to warn them beforehand and detect/prevent bad behavior on a best effort basis.

Comment: how about annotation processor ? Would it be possible to implement solution for this case?

Comment: maybe kotlin contracts can help with this use case? https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/kotlin-contracts.md

Answer (score 2):

For this, functions simply aren't an appropriate type. I'd declare a type whose values correspond to methods of `S`, so

```
class S { 
    fun method1(x: String): S = ...
    fun method2(): S = ...
    ...

    sealed class Transform {
        operator fun invoke(s: S): S = when(this) {
            is Method1 -> s.method1(x)
            is Method2 -> s.method2()
            ...
        }

        class Method1(val x: String) : Transform
        object Method2 : Transform
    }
}

fun emit(reduction: S.Transform) {
    state = reduction.invoke(state)
    if (_uiState.value != state) {
        _uiState.postValue(state)
    }
}
```

With some effort, `Transform` can be auto-generated (e.g. using an annotation processor, as you mention in a comment), but it may not be worth it depending on how many classes and methods you need to handle and how often they change.

Comment: thanks, it will solve my issues. (also logging called functions will be easier)